# jQuery load not working with certain .txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery load script that strangely works with a text file hosted in one location but not in another. For example, this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHRau/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
       $("#div10").load("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29635158/replace.txt", function () {
          alert("Done Loading");
       });
    });
});
```

...works just fine and is able to load the .txt document from my Dropbox.

But this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5TVT/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#div10").load("http://hs.biocanvas.net/files/replace.txt", function () {
           alert("Done Loading");
        });
    });
});
```

...is the exact same script with the exact same `.txt` file, except that `.txt` file is now hosted on a different server (and the URL accordingly changed in the script). However, the `.txt` file isn't loaded into the targeted div.

Both `.txt` files are readable if you <kbd>copy</kbd> + <kbd>paste</kbd> their URLs into a browser.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Two things, do you get errors in the console? and why will you use txt files? :S

Comment: Console gives  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header there should be your problem

Comment: you got your answer bellow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be a cross-domain request.
If you are using PHP or other server technology, you need allow the permissions in your application, but if you are using phonegap, that not is necessary.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.org/

Or, if it’s a public resource:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

As reference, you can read this post:
[HTTP access control (CORS) Developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

or [AJAX - Introducing Cross-domain Request (XDR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm completely naive when it comes to this...where would I go about changing these permissions?

Comment: If you're using apache, for example, you could do it through an .htaccess file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467673/enable-cors-in-htaccess Other webservers have similar ways of setting these parameters.

Comment: Are you using PHP, .Net what technology? or only javascript?

Comment: The server is on Apache, I believe...I'm trying to edit the .htaccess

Comment: I set the header access and the trick was to empty my cache, then it worked. Thank you so much to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late - but just to confirm user3294396 answer, if you run the code and look in the console, you'll probably see an error like:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hs.biocanvas.net/files/replace.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So you need to set up explicit access on the server.

Comment: I've attempted to edit the .htaccess with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * but it hasn't worked...I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (and I'm sadly a complete novice at these things...)

Comment: If you're using Apache (and it sounds like you are) - could you post what you've added for .htaccess? Have you tried restarting apache after making the edit?

Comment: I've fixed it...I think it just took a while for my server to update the file, but this is what I added into each relevant directory into the .htaccess file to fix it:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *