# Custom HTTP Header for a specific file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-headers, service-worker

I am trying to set a header for a specific file via my htaccess file in order to give my service worker access to my root. Unfortunately I don't see the header appearing... Perhaps I am not targeting the file (https://www.stefanklokgieters.nl/wp-content/themes/stefanklokgieters/serviceworker.js) correctly?

```
# Add custom header to single file
<Files "/wp-content/themes/stefanklokgieters/serviceworker.js">
Header set Service-Worker-Allowed "/"
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Many thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 10):

In a [`Files`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#files) directive, you can not match against file path, you can match against **filename.ext** only

```
<Files "serviceworker.js">
Header Set Service-Worker-allowed "/"
</Files>
```

Put this in an .htaccess file in the appropriate subdirectory, to restrict it to this path only, e.g. `/path/to/wp-content/themes/stefanklokgieters/.htaccess`

Comment: If you don't like the changes, just do a rollback.