# Implementing a POST API call in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm attempting to make a POST request to an API. I've created a javascript file in my theme and i have tried two approaches so far:

**Approach 1:**

```
$.ajax({
        headers:{  
            "Content-Type":"application/json"               
        },   
        data:{
            "command": "request",
            "data": {
                "api_key": "my_api_key",
                "api_username": "my_api_username",
                "vendor_type": 2,
                "from": {
                  "from_name": "",
                  "from_lat": "",
                  "from_long": "",
                  "from_description": ""
                },
                "to": {
                  "to_name": customerLocation,
                  "to_lat": cityLat,
                  "to_long": cityLng,
                  "to_description": ""
                },
                "recepient": {
                    "recepient_name": name,
                    "recepient_phone": phone,
                    "recepient_email": email,
                    "recepient_notes": ""
                },
                "delivery_details": {
                  "pick_up_date": pickupdate,
                  "collect_payment": {
                    "status": false,
                    "pay_method": 0,
                    "amount": amountTotal
                  },
                                      "return": true,
             "note": " Sample note",
              "note_status": true,
              "request_type": "quote"
            }
            },
            "request_token_id": requestToken
            },
        type: 'POST',
        url:"https://apitest.sendyit.com/v1/",
        success: function(response){
           console.log('success');
           console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

The above code will not return a response payload from the API as any call will be blocked because of CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

**Approach 2**

I then attempt to pass the endpoint to my `functions.php` file as follows:

```
//make api call to sendy
function foo() 
{
     echo 'https://apitest.sendyit.com/v1/';
}
add_action('wp_ajax_foo', 'foo' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foo', 'foo' );
```

I declare an `ajaxUrl` variable in my theme's header.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

Then format my Ajax call as shown below:

```
$.ajax({
        headers:{  
            "Content-Type":"application/json"               
        },   
        data:{
            "action": 'foo',
            "command": "request",
            "data": {
                "api_key": "my_api_key",
                "api_username": "my_api_username",
                "vendor_type": 2,
                "from": {
                  "from_name": "",
                  "from_lat": "",
                  "from_long": "",
                  "from_description": ""
                },
                "to": {
                  "to_name": customerLocation,
                  "to_lat": cityLat,
                  "to_long": cityLng,
                  "to_description": ""
                },
                "recepient": {
                    "recepient_name": name,
                    "recepient_phone": phone,
                    "recepient_email": email,
                    "recepient_notes": ""
                },
                "delivery_details": {
                  "pick_up_date": pickupdate,
                  "collect_payment": {
                    "status": false,
                    "pay_method": 0,
                    "amount": amountTotal
                  },
                                      "return": true,
             "note": " Sample note",
              "note_status": true,
              "request_type": "quote"
            }
            },
            "request_token_id": requestToken
            },
        type: 'POST',
        url:ajaxUrl,
        success: function(response){
           console.log('success');
           console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

But this is giving me a `400 (Bad Request)` error.

I should mention that i have correctly set up my javascript file in the `functions.php` file:

```
wp_enqueue_script('sendy', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/sendy.js', array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('sendy', 'wc_checkout_params', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

Would like therefore to request for assistance in setting up my POST endpoint.

Comment: `url:ajaxurl` should be `url:ajaxUrl`.

Comment: hi @cabrerahector. corrected but still getting 400 error

Comment: Can you enable CORS?  Then it just might work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467673/enable-cors-in-htaccess

Comment: hi @AaronBelchamber. tried all that already and isn't working. tried enabling in the .htaccess file and also in my header file and still nothing. could this mean my server does not allow it?