# Ionic 3 , videojs-panorama not supporting in Android getting error DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, video.js

I am getting this error when using 
videos-panorama

Dom Exception: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The video element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.

https://github.com/yanwsh/videojs-panorama

```
<code>
```

(function (window, videojs) {
      var player = window.player = videojs('videojs-panorama-player', {}, function () {
      });
      var videoElement = document.getElementById("videojs-panorama-player");
      var width = videoElement.offsetWidth;
      var height = videoElement.offsetHeight;
      player.width(width), player.height(height);
      player.panorama({
        clickAndDrag: true,
        backToVerticalCenter: false,
        backToHorizonCenter: false,
        clickToToggle: true,
        maxLat: -10,
        initLat: -10,
        initLon: -270,
        rotateX: -Math.PI,
        NoticeMessage: (isMobile()) ? "please drag and drop the video" : "please use your mouse drag and drop the video",
        videoType: "fisheye",
        callback: function () {
          player.play();
        }
      });
    }(window, window.videojs));

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "CORS" is explained here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

There is an earlier thread here on Stack-Overflow discussing this here:
[enable cors in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467673/enable-cors-in-htaccess)

To boil it all down, most webservers are happy, if you just supply them with
a two-line file named
".htaccess", containing these 2 lines:

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"