# VideoJS skin not showing on Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, video, media-player, video.js, skin

I am trying to implement a videojs player on a basic web page with the [Sublime skin](https://codepen.io/zanechua/pen/GozrNe).

I have added the source links from the [videojs website](https://videojs.com/getting-started/#customize), copied the html and css from the codepen above however the default player is loading and not the skin. The web page also never stops loading, I have to hit the x button on the browser.

The console is fine and there are no errors.

I think I am missing something but I don't know what! Any help appreciated. I don't have a live version of this web page but if it helps I can put it online. Thanks!

From the Sublime Codepen:

```html
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/video-feature.css">

   <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.5/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-sublime-skin" width="640px" height="267px"
      controls preload="none" poster='https://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.jpg'
      data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
     <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
     <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm' />
        <p class='vjs-no-js'>
       To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
       <a href='https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/' target='_blank'>supports HTML5 video</a>
     </p>
   </video>

   <script src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.5/video.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: When I run your snippet in Chrome, I see numerous errors in the debugging console that you need to resolve. (I've never seen those exact same errors, but they sound quite similar to cross-origin errors mentione here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691058/  )