# Angular 8 with php and mysql database Cross-Origin Request Blocked:

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cross-domain, angular8

I am trying to build a login and register with angular 8 platform, 
with php and mysql database.

php and mysql uses `localhost/` and angular 8 uses `localhost:4200`.

I am trying to send data to mysql database but there is a error message in the console:

[image]

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked:

To communicate between localhost/ and localhost:4200 i used this code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]    

#Set the headers for the restful api 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:4200   
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin,    Authorization,    
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

but still I am getting this error. Is there anybody to help me?

Comment: Your .htaccess is not valid. A lot of the quotes are wrong and/or missing. Correct syntax is: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * (no quotes). Did you take a look in the apache log?

Comment: bro thanks for replying. I am beginner to this platform. Can you send me correct syntax of htaccess file

Comment: And bro i dont to check apache log can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

From [enable cors in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467673/enable-cors-in-htaccess) (this question is a duplicate!) You need to use add instead of set. Remove all the rules and replace by:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

The asterisk *should* be replaced by the correct domain in production mode.