# React has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: reactjs, cors, laravel-5.7

According to this answers [enable cors in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467673/enable-cors-in-htaccess) I would like to allow cross-origin requests from React application to the local server with Laravel application. So I added these lines at the beginning of my public/.htaccess. But it does not work.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

The error says:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8000/api/page/dynamic/111170/1' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Can somebody tell me please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alternatively, you can try this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US) and enable it. This is just for local testing purpose.

Answer (score -1):

In your server you need to enable requests from the local host:3000 origin. By default most server frameworks will block requests that aren’t from its own ip. This is called a cross origin request policy and its to help secure your application.

You’ll need to change your servers CORS policy to include localhost:3000 - you’ll need to google how to do this for the specific server framework you’ve chosen.

To reiterate, this is not a problem with your React code but with your server.

Comment: I know. But this sould be able to do in .htaccess. It should be allowed on page level not on server level. I mentioned it in the question.