# CORS fonts errors/ wordpress/elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, cors, elementor

I need to set the CORS on website build on wordpress, and what I made:

I have added code to .htaccess and functions.php on my template as below. However, I the app with other domain still cannot load the fonts. I have even tested it with CORS tester, and there is information it should work perfectly. But it doesn`t...

The website is build on wordpress 5.3 and Elementor. Fonts are uploaded to Elementor.

I have even used another plugin for custom fonts, added @font-face css... and nothing...
The errors about CORS still existing while checking console. Please, could anybody has any ideas how to fix it? I am getting mad about...

Thank you

Added to .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)">
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Added to functions.php

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

Comment: consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467673/enable-cors-in-htaccess

Comment: thanks, but it also does not work. Server is Apache.

Comment: but you only set one of about 3 headers likely needed. Should at least set `Access-Control-Allow-Method`

Comment: thanks, but it still does not to work.... it seems Elementor is blocking icons and fonts...