# Flutter: CORS blocked getting images from another wp site

Tags: php, flutter, rest, cors, wordpress-rest-api

My flutter app works well on android and iOS. Now I am trying to publish my app also on web (Domain: webapp.ockenheim.de).

But every GET Request of data from [https://app.ockenheim.de](https://app.ockenheim.de/) was blocked by CORS.

Then I added header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://webapp.ockennheim.de" ); to function.php of my template.

I also tried adding

`header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" );`

Now I can make CORS requests to custom REST API endpoints. Only the "Network Image" requests of Flutter App are blocked now:

`Cross-Origin request blocked: The same origin rule block reading https://app.ockenheim.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Screenshot_20221202_121659-1.jpg. (reason: CORS-header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing). Statuscode: 200.`

The code which loads the image from flutter:

```
Container(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: double.infinity,
                maxWidth: double.infinity,
              ),
              width: 10000,
              //height: double.infinity,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
              //height: 170,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: NetworkImage(cardModell.bild),
              )),
```

Does someone have a clue, how to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to get your webserver to provide the CORS headers when responding to image requests. You can't do that from php as it doesn't serve those, it'll be a webserver config thing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: @ADyson Is there a way of dealing with it by .htaccess? 
I do not have access to config the server (plesk).

Comment: I'd expect one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467673/enable-cors-in-htaccess) might work (except the PHP-based one). Or there are more results [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+add+cors+headers+to+images)

Answer (score -1):

had the same problem a while ago.

When you declaring your your URL to the endpoint don't use like this:

```
Uri request =
    Uri(scheme: 'https', host: 'endpoint.com', path: '/api/path');
```

Instead use like this:

```
  http.Response response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse("https://completeurlwhitpath.com/api/path"));
```

Hope this helps you, didn't needed any configuration of CORS or anything on my end, only this change solves the problem for Flutter Web.